# How to remove the notification "1000 Unread Messages" beside login logo in Windows XP?

Tags: windows-xp, thunderbird, login, notifications

My sister computer have three logins: 1.) Administrator 2.) Limited Account 3.) Guest

Everytime the pc is open, the Admin login have notification beside it saying: 1000 Unread Messages. How to remove that?

I once read messages there using Portable Thunderbird (from a USB stick), maybe it is the cause of the notification.

But it sticks there everytime the pc is open, no usb stick is attached, but the notification remains.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can completely disable the `x unread messages` 'feature' by following these steps:

1. Click Start > Run
2. Type in 'regedit'
3. Go to
   `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\UnreadMail`
4. Right click in right hand pane and click New > DWORD. Name it
   `MessageExpiryDays`
5. Double click the new `MessageExpiryDays` DWORD
   and make sure the value is `0`

Done! Make sure you reboot after this!

If you only want to do this to the currently logged in account, then do the same as above, but go here instead of the place I said in step 3:

NOT THIS:
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\UnreadMail`

BUT THIS:
`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\UnreadMail`

<sup><sup><sup>[Source](http://www.ehow.com/how_7326229_delete-unread-messages-windows-startup.html)</sup></sup></sup>

Screenshot:

[image]

Alternatively, you could install [Tweak UI Power Toy](http://windowsxp.mvps.org/tweakui.htm). Click Login (at the bottom) > Unread Mail.

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I will try tomorrow when I get there at my sister house. I will ask you again tomorrow if it works or not. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Mail clients store the unread mail count in Registry. Open `regedit`, navigate to the key

- HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\UnreadMail

and either delete the subkeys (subfolders) corresponding to mail accounts, or set their `MessageCount` values to zero.

[image: screenshot]

<sup>(Apologies for the lack of freehand circles today.)</sup>

Comment: Thanks. I will try tomorrow when I get there at my sister's house. I will ask again tomorrow if it works or not. Thanks.